# Pubnub One to One Chat Sending Message to all users

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, chat, real-time, pubnub

This is My Pubnub Chat Code

```
 var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key   : 'my_key',
    subscribe_key : 'sub-key'
});

  pubnub.subscribe({

    channel : "{{$channel}}",

    message : function(m){

     $(".conversation-list").append(
        '<li class="clearfix '+ m.clearifix +' ">' +
        '<div class="chat-avatar">' +
        '<img src="' + m.image + '">'+
        '<i> {{date('h:i')}}  </i>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="conversation-text">' +
        '<div class="ctext-wrap">' +
        '<i> '+ m.name + '</i>' +
        '<p>' + m.message + '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</li>'
        ).animate({scrollTop: $(".conversation-list")[0].scrollHeight}, 0);
     $('.reply-text').val('');

 },
     //connect : publish
 });

  $('.send-reply-to-user').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('.reply-text').val()== '')
        return false;
    else

        console.log(pubnub.publish);
   // console.log(this);

    var user_to_id = $(".send-reply-to-user").attr('user_to_id');
    var message = $('.reply-text').val();
    var name = $('#user_name').val();
    var image = document.getElementById("user_image").getAttribute("src");
    var clearifix = $('#user_clearifx').val();

    pubnub.publish({
        channel : "{{$channel}}",
        message: { name : name, message : message, image : image, clearifix : clearifix }
    });

    if ($.trim(message).length != 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{route('send:user:chat:message')}}',
            cache: false,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {user_to_id: user_to_id, message: message, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (result) {
            }

        })
    }

});
```

This code is Working perfectly only problem is that messages are going to all users, I want to send msg to one to one user.

```
Example: User one: John send a message to User two Deo, 
Example 2: John sends a message to Marry
```

and so on. Using Pubnub JS API, Backend as Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Fixed My issue, the private Channels working good , Actually problem was with my back-end. It was returning data from all the users i have fixed now its working fine.

Comment: will you please share the source code, if possible?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using PubNub's opinionated JavaScript framework called [ChatEngine](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/getting-started). It takes away a lot of the heavy lifting involved with making chat with PubNub. Here is some example code to get you started making 1:1 private chats. Make sure you use the [setup button](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/getting-started#automagic-pubnub-setup) to prepare the backend on your account.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chat-engine@0.9.5/dist/chat-engine.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Init ChatEngine with PubNub
const publishKey = '__Your_PubNub_Publish_Key__';
const subscribeKey = '__Your_PubNub_Subscribe_Key__';

const ChatEngine = ChatEngineCore.create({
  publishKey,
  subscribeKey,
}, {
  globalChannel: 'global',
});

const user = {
    uuid: 'randomstringofchars',
    name: 'John Smith'
}

const chats = {};

ChatEngine.connect(user.uuid, user);

ChatEngine.on('$.ready', function(data) {

    // store my new user as `me`
    let me = data.me;

    // returns a ChatEngine chat object
    function makePrivateChat(theirUserId) {
        const chatKey = [theirUserId, me.uuid].sort().join('-');

        // Don't make the same 1:1 chat if it already exists
        if (chats[chatKey]) {
            return;
        }

        // true for private chat
        const chat = new ChatEngine.Chat(chatKey, true);

        chats[chatKey] = chat;
    }

    // Auto add a 1:1 chat to UI when invited by someone
    me.direct.on('$.invite', makePrivateChat);

    // Define a button for making new 1:1 chats in your UI
    newOneToOneChatButton.on('click', function (event, theirUserId) {
        someChatObject.invite(theirUserId);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this means all users are stored within single global channel with separating Id's , how can i find chats of single users when i retrieve the chat??

Comment: All users that join the app are connected to the global chat. They all have different `uuids` that you can define. You can make your own individual private chats like in my answer. Each of the chat objects are stored in `ChatEngine.chats`.